# Using utf-8 in php and loading file (require_once) gives strange char

Tags: php, html, utf-8, require-once

In place where I use `require_once('something.php');` I have strange char in html and when I check page on validator:

```
Validation Output: 1 Error 
Error Line 1, Column 1: character "" not allowed in prolog
```

This only happens when I'm using UTF-8. Earlier I have files in ANSI and it was ok.

Yes I'm changing meta and save all files in UTF-8
I can move code to section body but this is strange for me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So? Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, but I can't now make your answer useful ;)

Comment: What do you mean? So what was the cause? It would be nice to add it as an answer or I can update my answer. It's up to you. But we should post it here definitely, so it has some value for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably caused by the [UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Open any file in some HEX viewer / editor and check the first 3 bytes in that file.

UTF-8 BOM in Windows-1250 encoding looks like this: `ď»ż`. Or `ï»¿` in ISO-8859-1. That's `EF BB BF` in hexadecimal.

Just save your files as UTF-8 **without BOM**. For example [Notepad++ editor](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) has both options under `Format` menu:

- Convert into UTF-8 (without BOM)
- Convert into UTF-8

Comment: Thx, can I save in sharepoint designer 2007 without BOM? May be interfering with files from program?

Comment: I have no clue about Sharepoint Designer, but I would advice you to not using it as I know Microsoft's software. Use that Notepad++, it's free, open-source, lightweight and good. And it does what user wants, not what it thinks is best for user.